# combine both a free text bow with a select box

Tags: jquery, html, select, input

I'm working on a small piece of front-end functionality and would like to have the best of both worlds. :)

Currently I'm using an input box so that we don't restrict and test values being submitted, however, each of these inputs has a finite range of valid values.
It would be nice to have the option of selecting from the valid values OR entering free text.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I'm hedging my bets towards a jquery library that might swap the inputs out on an icon click but thought it worth asking the community for pro-tips

Comment: [chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) provides this functionality

Comment: I have used [select2](https://select2.github.io/) on some projects. I think it allows enabling input that doesn't match the source data.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers :  I looked at both the libraries noted in the comments and both are perfectly suitable for this type of functionality.  I stuck with chosen.js as it was the first one. :D